# Is it possible to have an embedded system within an embedded system?

Tags: embedded

Is it possible to have an embedded system within an embedded system? Are there embedded systems within the embedded system of a Sony Alpha 6000 camera?

Can you nest embedded systems?

Comment: Yes, you can but I do not believe the distinction is useful

Comment: @DKNguyen Can you give me an example of this? I am confused about this concept

Comment: A robot is an embedded system and it might have a machine vision sensor which in itself is an embedded system.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thank you.

Comment: Using fuzzy big picture terms like "embedded system" when trying to understand or categorize technology is probably not very helpful.

Comment: @Lundin Why is it not very helpful?

Comment: It is just not useful. When would you need to use such a classification? What practical communicative purpose would it serve?

Comment: @DKNguyen I am getting a grasp of how to use Embedded Systems in everyday language. It helps me understand what an Embedded System is.

Comment: That in itself is fuzzy enough it isn't worth splitting hairs over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very much possible to find embedded type designs that nest. The nested embedded systems would be considered subsystems.

A simple example in today's common experience could be the design of some microcontroller based gadget that uses a module as a subsystem such as a BlueTooth module or a GPS receiver. Both modules like these very often have their own microcontroller or microcontroller core running its own firmware. These modules unto themselves are embedded systems.